# How to find the current view controller in iOS

Tags: ios, viewcontroller

The entrance of my app is a `UINavgationViewController`. The root view controller is a `UITabBarViewController`. The `UITabBarViewController` contains some normal `UIViewController`s. These controllers may call:

`self.navgationController.pushViewcontroller(otherViewController, animated:true);`

However, I have another thread running in the background. How can I know which view controller is currently being shown on the main screen?

I tried to call `UIApplication.keywindows.rootviewcontroller` but it returns `UINavgationViewController`.

`UINavgationViewController.viewcontrollers.count == 1`, it only contains a `UITabBarViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get the selected view controller from your tab bar:

```
navigationController.tabBarController.selectedViewController
```

Answer (score 0):

try by using `viewDidAppear` method in every view controller class

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
        NSLog(@"Currennt view:%@",self);
}
```

`self` returns name of ViewController class

Answer (score 0):

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];


NSLog(@"%@",appDelegate.navController.topViewController);
```

You can get the top most `Controller` that is pushed.